# Set an URL in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create an app in Flask/Python.

I have an `index.html` which has one form. If you fill this form in and press enter, it return `results.html` which contains information according to the query you filled in.

My problem is that the URL is still `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html` but I would like to have a `http://127.0.0.1:5000/results.html`

How could I do that?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import request,render_template,Flask,redirect
from databases import db_manager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

def is_instance(a):
    return isinstance(a,basestring)

app.jinja_env.globals.update(is_instance=is_instance)


@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        if query.isdigit():
            _data = db_manager.manager().get_subject_by_ICO(query)
        else:
            _data = db_manager.manager().get_subject_by_name(query)   
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('results.html', data = _data)

@app.route('/')
def to_index():
    return redirect('/index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to make this url (results.html) available you'll need to add an appropriate route

```
@app.route('/results.html')
```

Next thing is that the way your code works now - it doesn't redirect user to another url after make a post request on index.html. You just render results.html template at the same url (index.html). To achieve your goal you'll need to redirect user to results.html and save the data that you want to display there using some client related storage (for example, storage).

Comment: Thanks. It is possible to redirect to results.html with the arguments? (_data)

Comment: You can otherwise redirect using GET argument and the retrieve them from request, or set data in user's cookie and then read them in view for /results.html